# open dialogue box file

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

I want to display pop up or dialogue box in form view to import the file (big file) (300MB) I use (binary field) (many2many) but chrome crash when save or make any method finally I want to get path of file imported  to copy to another  directory 
is this any way or solution to fix that

Answer (score 0):

In the import file function you need to check file size and set your pop up or dialogue box (odoo wizard).

put blow code inside your import function:

```
import os #import library
file_size = os.path.getsize('file_name.csv')
file_max_size = 2626 #max file size in byte

if file_size <= file_max_size:
    print("File accept code and next step")
else:
    print("File not accept code(pop-up)")
```